# passing value between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm having some difficulty passing values and arrays between this two functions

Here's the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        ....
        ....    
    var srcImageFS =$('#imageAnimated').attr('src');    
    var array = []; 
    $('.myLightbox').each(function(i) {
         array.push($('.myLightbox').eq(i).attr('href'));
    });

    $('#rightArrowFS').click(function(array, srcImageFS ){
            alert(array +' || --> ' +srcImageFS );
            imageRight();

        });
...
...
});
```

and

```
function imageRight(array, srcImageFS ){
        $('#imageAnimated').fadeOut();
        $('#imageAnimated').src(array[i+1]);
        $('#imageAnimated').fadeIn();
        srcImageFS = $('#imageAnimated').src();
        arrowsState(array, srcImageFS );
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to pass and how?

Comment: what are you trying to pass?
Is imagemAnimada same as imageAnimated ? i think you have a typo here

Comment: Just uppdate the code wit the correct names. Sorry about that. I'm trying to pass array and srcImageFS. I trid to  imageRight( array, srcImageFS); but without success. The alert gives me [object Object] || --> undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example code, you don't actually try to pass anything to `imageRight` - the parameter list is empty.  Also, you overwrite the value of `srcImageFS` inside `imageRight` before using it.

`srcImageFS` is undefined because jQuery couldn't find a `src` attribute on `$('#imageAnimated')` so your selector might be wrong, too.

```
imageRight(array, srcImageFS);
```

Will actually call the function with the arguments you want.

Comment: yap you are right. thanks. on the second block of code I want to change the source of #imageAnimated. I tried $('#imageAnimated').src(array[i+1]); , but var i is not passed. Do you have any idea how can I do it??

Comment: `.attr('src', array[i+1])`

`src` is an attribute http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/

Answer (score 1):

in the document.ready function where ur calling the imageRight() function u should instead call
imageRight(array, srcImageFS ) ur nt passing any values to the function